# -bash: syntax error near unexpected token '(' when running Java program from command line

Tags: java, bash

I am trying to figure out why I am getting a -bash: syntax error near unexpected token '(' when attempting to run a basic calculator java program from command line.

The project has been finished submitted and graded already, so no academic dishonesty intended.

In my terminal (macOs 10.13.6) I am running the program using:

```
java InfixExpressionEvaluator (a+b)*(c-9) "a=1 b=2 c=3";
```

where `(a+b) * (c-9)` is the expression to be evaluated with the given variables following. However, every time I get -bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('. Is this due to the formatting of the expression `(a+b) * (c-9)`? I am not familiar with bash scripting, but from some google searches it appear as though the terminal is attempting to interpret the '(' as part of a script, and to get around this I would need to place `(a+b) * (c-9)` within quotations i.e. `"(a+b) * (c-9)"`. Is this correct, or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Your personal research led you to a solution. What happened when you tried that solution? Is there something stopping you from trying the solution that you found?

Comment: "*it appear as though the terminal is attempting to interpret*" - no, not the terminal, it is `bash`.  As a general case it is safer to use single quotes if you don't want any expansion (`$` and `\`` are candidates for expansion inside double quotes).

Comment: @mypetlion, I should have clarified, my confusion comes from my professor telling me that it should work run from the command line without surrounding the expression to be evaluated single or double quotations.

Comment: @r.foggio Don't know what to tell you there. Maybe your professor is wrong. Maybe they're using a different shell that uses a different syntax. You'll have to clarify with them.

Answer (score 1):

The "expression to be evaluated" needs to be quoted because it contains several characters (`(`, `)`, `*`) that have special significance to Bash.  This should work:

```
java InfixExpressionEvaluator '(a+b)*(c-9)' 'a=1 b=2 c=3'
```

No expansions are needed, so I used single quotes instead of double quotes.  I removed the trailing `;` because Bash doesn't need it.